# Signing in to Google through very different IP addresses

Tags: google-account, security, authentication, ip-addresses

Because I connect to many different VPNs and make it appear that I'm in very different geographical locations, how do I add a `whitelist` of IP addresses that are allowed to sign in to my account so I don't get an

> "unrecognized device tried signing in to your account"

error message?